# Should you use "in Fortnite" or "on Fortnite"?

Tags: prepositions

Just so that you understand Fornite is a video game and team deathmatch is a game mode.

So here are two sentences:

> 1. He wants to play team deathmatch in Fortnite.
> 2. He wants to play team deathmatch on Fortnite.

I think the second one is right, but I am not sure about the first one. Also, are there other grammatically valid ways of saying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another grammatically correct way of saying this would be:

> He wants to play Fortnite in team deathmatch mode.

Comment: Is the first one correct though?

Comment: In, the first one is correct.

Comment: This is exactly what I said 2 hours ago, but I have a -3 reputation, any explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Either one is correct, and they have slightly different shades of meaning. Expanding your sentences to make those meanings explicit:

> 1. He wants to play team deathmatch **in** the online game, Fortnite.

The preposition **in** emphasizes the idea that you are metaphorically "inside" the game-world.  The preposition **in** is frequently used this way with video games: "Which character do you usually play **in** Mario Kart?"

> 2. He wants to play in team deathmatch mode hosted **on** a Fortnite server.

The preposition **on** emphasizes the technological infrastructure of a MMOPRG and the fact that you're logging on to a shared deathmatch server along with the other players. You would not use **on** when talking about a stand-alone console game, because you're not logging **on** to any remote server.

Answer (score -2):

You must say:

> He wants to play Fortnite **in** team matchmaking mode.

Comment: in matchmaking mode